# Find all functions $F(x)$ satisfying $F(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find all functions $F(x)$ satisfying $F(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ such that $F(0)=9$ and $|f(x)| \le 2$ and $f(x)$ is thrice differentiable function

One possibility i could get is $f(x)=3sinx$ and $f'(x)=3cosx$ which satisfies $|f(x)| \le 2$ so $F(x)=9$ any other functions possible? With given information above which of the following is/are True

EDIT:

A) there is at least one point in each of intervals  $(-2 \: \: 0)$ and $(0 \:\: 2)$ such that $|f'(x)| \le 2$

B)  there is at least one point in each of intervals  $(-2 \:\: 0)$ and $(0 \:\: 2)$ such that $F(x) \le 8$

C)there is no point of Local maxima in $(-2\: \: 2)$ for $F(x)$

D)For some $c \in (-2 \:\: 2)$ $F(c) \ge 9$, $F'(c)=0$ and $F''(c) \le0$

Comment: It does not satisfy the property $|f(x)| \le 2$ take $x =\pi /2$ for example you get $3$

Comment: I'm a bit confused here.  If there are no more conditions required (only the value of $F(0)$, and that $f$ is bounded and differentiable), then there are tons of solutions.  Just take an arbitrary bounded, thrice differentiable function, scale it to bounded it by $2$, and stretch/compress it horizontally to control the value of $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ at zero.  You are going to need more constraints if you want a small class of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider $f(x) = a \sin (bx + \phi)$ such that $a \leq 2$.

In order to satisfy the other constraint: $F(0)= a^2(\sin^2 \phi+ b^2 \cos^2 \phi)=a^2(1+(b^2-1)\cos^2 \phi )=9$

So, $b^2 = (\frac{9}{a^2}-1)\sec^2 \phi+1$ (considering $\cos \phi \neq 0$).

[Not sure whether there is any more solution exists.]